# How to time a SLURM job array?

Tags: slurm

I am submitting a SLURM job array and want to have the total runtime (i.e. not the runtime of each task) printed to the log.

This is what I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=step1
#SBATCH --output=logs/step1.log
#SBATCH --error=logs/step1.log
#SBATCH --array=0-263%75

start=$SECONDS

python worker.py ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID} 

echo "Completed step1 in $SECONDS seconds"
```

What I get in step1.log is something like this:

```
Completed step1 in 42 seconds
Completed step1 in 94 seconds
Completed step1 in 88 seconds
...
```

which appear to be giving the runtimes for the last group of tasks in the array.  I want a single timer for the whole array, from submission to the end of the last task.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

With job arrays, each task is an identical submission of your script, so the way you're measuring time will necessarily only be per-task, as you're seeing. To get the overall elapsed time of the entire jobarray, you'll need to get the *submit time of the first task* and subtract it from the *end time of the last task*.

e.g.

```
# get submit time for first task in array
sacct -j <job_id>_0 --format=submit

# get end time for last task in array
sacct -j <job_id>_263 --format=end
```

Then use `date -d <timestamp from sacct> +%s` to convert the timestamps to seconds since the epoch, to make them easier to subtract.

Also note that each of your 264 tasks will overwrite `step1.log` with its own output. I would typically use `#SBATCH --output=step1-%A_%a.out` to distinguish outputs from different tasks.